# Shell Script- sed pattern to insert comma in a string variable before a specific keyword

Tags: bash, shell

In bash/shell script,

I have a string variable "metaItems" with 2 values

```
metaItems= src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile
```

i want to insert comma before every "src/" value and store the values in an array as shown below
for e.g

```
array= {src/profiles/API Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile}
```

how to achieve it ?

Comment: Please use https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @PravindraSinghKhatri : A string variable can have only one value. At best, the value can have an embedded space, what would be the case if your assignment would be syntactic correct. Please take the time to post exactly the code you have, as it makes discussion easier. An array variable can contain more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want to insert a `','`, but instead you want to insert a `'\n'` so that you can set `IFS` (*Internal Field Separator*) to word-split on the newline and separate your strings into separate elements of an array.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

metaItems="src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile"

oifs="$IFS"     # save original IFS
IFS=$'\n'       # set IFS to split on '\n'

arr=( $(sed 's|\ src/|\nsrc/|g' <<< $metaItems) )

IFS="$oifs"     # restore original IFS

declare -p arr
```

**Example Use/Output**

With the above script in `splitarray`,

```
$ bash splitarray
declare -a arr=([0]="src/profiles/API Only.profile" [1]="src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile")
```

Which show your desired strings separated into individual elements of the array `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "metaItems= src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile" | sed -r -e "s/([^=]) src/\1,src/g" -e "s/metaItems= (.*)/array= {\1}/"
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$echo  $metaItems 
src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile
$IFS=',' read -ra array <<< $(echo  $metaItems | sed 's#src\/#,&#g') 
$for i in "${array[@]}"; do echo $i; done

src/profiles/API Only.profile
src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile
$
```